# How to safely dispose an object in a thread while another thread could use the object in Delphi?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety

How to safely dispose an object in a thread while another thread could use the object in Delphi?
Any ideas or articles to read about?

Comment: Never Free an object when it is still accessible. Never.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to make sure that other threads are no longer using the object before you can safely dispose of it.

Wrap all access to the object with a lock, such as a critical section or mutex.

Or make the object be reference counted. Have each thread increment the refcount while working with the object, and decrement it when finished. Then you can dispose of the object after its refcount has been decremented to 0.  Writing a [`TInterfacedObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/TInterfacedObject)-derived class that implements a Delphi [`interface`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Interfaces) will work very well for this purpose and do the bulk of the work for you automatically.

Comment: There are examples in the documentation I linked to.

Comment: @qgi read any examples about OmniThreadLibrary - their collections and almost all other primitives are exactly that ARC-objects made for multithreading-use. Or read any article about working with Word/Excel via COM interfaces - those interfaces are mapped into Delphi ARC-objects too, though those article would not expose multi-threading program design.